# How to evaluate matlab fit objects in a cell array without looping?

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization, curve-fitting, cell-array

I have an array of fit objects and I need to evaluate each of them with several values. Because there are over thousand of those fit objects I find it very slow to loop over them and evaluate them with the values. So is there a way to use some kind of vectorized solution to this?

For example I can evaluate a single fit object by

```
fitArray{1,1}(400)
```

but what I would like to do is to evaluate multiple fit objects at a time in a way something like this:

```
fitArray{1:1000}(400)
```

The looping in Matlab is always very slow and in this case it's really slow as I need to evaluate each of those fits with multiple values.

So is there a way to do that without looping?

Comment: Your statement *The looping in Matlab is always very slow* is incorrect, and even more incorrect with recent versions of Matlab than with older versions.  The old adage that a vectorised solution is always faster is no longer true.  And sometimes difficult problems take a long time to solve, your expectations of finding a faster solution without a lot of hard work may well be unrealistic.

Comment: @zaplec, Have you tried using the `cellfun` function?

Comment: @slayton Yes I tried it before, but I didn't think about adding the input values as an array. Now I figured it out though and answered to this question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It was quite simple after all. I achieved the result I wanted by doing this:

```
vals = repmat({values}, size(fitArray));
evals = cellfun(@feval, fitArray, vals);
```

This evaluates each fit object in the cell array with the value in the corresponding row in the vals array. So the result is that the evals array has only the results of each fit object.

Answer (score 0):

Looping is not the biggest problem here, look for example at speed of fitoptions ... the memory allocation is terrible so try to do all operations before the loop itself (fitoptions, fittype etc...). If you use polynomial fitting and you don't need the cfit structure try polyfit instead - should be considerably faster.

Comment: The fitting has been done before and the cell array only contains the fit objects which I need to evaluate with certain values.